# How to attach images that I "insert from url" into the post?

Tags: post-thumbnails, attachments, images, get-children

I'm trying to get the list of images in my post, to display them in the front page... the problem is that when I add a new picture from a URL, it doesn't seem to attach it.

```
$images =& get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image' );
```

This returns an empty array... how can I solve this so I can actually use these images and create thumbnails to display them on the front?

Comment: Without more information is a bit hard to know what you're talking about. I found this online: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-all-images-attached-to-a-post-based-on-gallery

Answer (score 1):

A quick experiment with WordPress 3.5.1 shows that when you an image into post from URL, there's no post inserted into the wp_posts or wp_postmeta table - which is why the $images array is coming back empty.

You could write some JS on the admin side to create and insert a post asynchronously when you click the insert into post button - otherwise, you could use some Regex with `get_the_content()` to pull them from the content, which is likely more complicated and less reliable.

*EDIT Below is only applicable when uploading media and attaching to posts.*

Straight from the [WordPress Codex wp_get_attachment_image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) page:

> To display all of the images and titles attached to a certain page and
>   display them as a list of bullets you can use the following:

```
<ul>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           echo '<li>';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
           echo '<p>';
           echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
           echo '</p></li>';
          }
     }

 endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: you didn't read the post. The problem is that images that are added "via url" are not attached to the post